# how to assign an array by value to another variable  javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

i have an array `channel_chunk`

```
var channel = "global/private/user/updates/user_following/publisher_id/subcriber_id";

channel_chunk = channel.split("/"),
```

and i assign this array to another variable

```
var new_arr =  channel_chunk ;
```

the problem is

when i changed

```
new_arr[0]  = "test";
```

`channel_chunk[0]` also becomes `test`

so i think it is passed by reference when i am assigning , i want to assign `channel_chunk` by value to `new_arr` .

i know `jQuery.extend`  will help. but i am using pure JavaScript in this case , so i can not use it , is there a built in function to do this in JavaScript . please help............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "official" way to take a (shallow) copy of (part of) an array is [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var new_arr = channel_chunk.slice(0);
```

[ It's called a "shallow" copy because any objects or arrays therein will still refer to the originals, but the array itself is a whole new copy.  As you're using string primitives that won't affect you. ]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new array. An easy way to do this is simply concat with no args:

```
var new_arr = channel_chunk.concat();
```

Now modifying new_arr will have no effect on channel_chunk.